# Real Analysis Folland, Corollary 2.2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This follows from [Proposition 2.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493199/real-analysis-folland-proposition-2-1/1493260#1493260).

Corollary 2.2: If $X$ and $Y$ are metric (or topological) spaces, every continuous $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is $(\mathcal{B}_X,\mathcal{B}_Y,)$-measurable.

proof (similar to proof in book): Suppose we have a open set $U$ and we have $U\subset Y$. Since $f:X\rightarrow Y$ we can state that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Then since, $\mathcal{B}_X$ and $\mathcal{B}_Y$ are $\sigma$-algebras generated by the family of open or closed sets in the metric space $X$ and $Y$ respectively, then clearly $f$ is $(\mathcal{B}_X,\mathcal{B}_Y,)$-measurable.

I am not sure if this makes sense or not or if the proof is not rigorous enough, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it is not clear to you it's not clear (even though it is correct).  I would drop "and only if" and "or closed sets" since you don't use them.  A proof doesn't need extra fluff even if it is true fluff.  To make your argument compelling to you start with a lemma:  The collection of sets $$\left\{E:    f^{-1}(E) \in  B_X \right\} $$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: To clarify: the "if and only if" is what to drop.  Just use that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open if $U$ is open.   The lemma is to be proved for a completely arbitrary function $f:X\to Y$.   [This time limit on edits is harrassing me since I always need more time to correct my typing and my LaTeX.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is more or less correct, though you should clarify how exactly the result of Proposition 2.1 is used. Worded differently, Proposition 2.1 states that the function $f$ (as defined in that proposition) is measurable if and only if the preimage of every set that generates $N$ is a measurable set in $Y$ (i.e. it is an element of $M$).

To that end, let $\mathcal{O}_Y$ be the family of open sets in $Y$, then we know that this collection of sets generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_Y$. Given any open set $U_Y \in \mathcal{O}_Y$, we know that $f^{-1}(U_Y)$ is an open set of $X$, by continuity of $f$. Since the open sets of $X$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_X$ and $\sigma$-algebras always contain their generating sets, we have that $f^{-1}(U_Y) \in \mathcal{B}_X$ for every $U_Y \in \mathcal{O}_Y$ i.e. the preimage of every generating set of $\mathcal{B}_Y$ is measurable in $X$. By Proposition 2.1, we conclude that $f$ is a measurable function.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that if $U\subset Y$ is open then $f^{-1}(U)$ is an element of $\mathcal B_X$. Why is it "clear" (to you) that the same is true if $U$ is merely an element of $\mathcal B_Y$?